# Opening and writing to form from console aplication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, console-application

My goal is to add a existing project of a windows form with a textbox to a console project in Visual Studio. And by running the console program the form is opened and objects on the form such as a textbox can be written to in the console program.

I am having a issue of simply opening the form from the console application:

```cs
using GUI_VISUIALZATION;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

class program
{
    static void Main(string[]args)
    {
        GUI gUI = new GUI();
        gUI.Show();
    
        Console.ReadKey();    
    }
}
```

Name of program with form in it: `GUI VISUIALZATION`
Name of form:  `GUI`
Namespace of form: `GUI_VISUIALZATION`

Name of console project:  `ACTIVATE`

Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]

When console program is run

[image: when console program is ran]

Comment: GUI programs need the main thread to process windows events. You'll have to be careful to read the console without blocking that thread.

Comment: you should clarify weather you want the gui and console run in same **process** or not.

Comment: @RED: Seems like some of your program components is compiled as the `x86`, when the console application is compiled as `x64.` See description of [BadImageFormatException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-6.0)

Comment: This is non-trivial, and too broad of a question as asked; you're basically asking "How to implement communication between two separate processes?". There are quite a few solutions, but you need to look into IPC communication, pick a method, try it out, and come back with a specific question.

Comment: You need to create a Windows application. Then right click the project and go to properties and set the Output Type for the application to Console Application. This will then not only show your form but also the Console Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the form with a console application, you can refer to the following steps:

First add this code in .csproj file of the console application:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>  
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Second add project reference of GUI VISUIALZATION:
[image]

Finally you can refer to the following code in console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new GUI());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Here is the test result:**
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! YOU ARE A LIFESAVER

Comment: @RED I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.